# Sync Pictures folder on Windows partition

Tags: ubuntu-one

The Pictures folder in my home folder is actually a link to the Pictures folder in my Windows installation. When I try and sync this folder I get a message saying the folder is not valid. I am however able to Sync individual folders within the pictures folder, which seems strange. Is there any way I can sync the whole folder?

Answer (score 1):

Create a link to Windows user folder in Ubuntu home folder. Then I was able to sync the pictures folder by accessing it through the link I created.

Answer (score 0):

I have never liked the way that Windows uses links from the Documents/Pictures folders and have always opted to store my pictures in a "real" folder such as e:\nikon (e: being my data drive).  Then, it's a simple matter to backup (or sync - using something like FreeFileSync) the actual folder.

But, isn't the Pictures folder actually a real folder located at something like C:\Users\your_username\Pictures?  If you can locate this folder, you should be able to sync it.

Comment: I know where the folder is located. Because I dual boot, and I had Windows first, it's more convenient for me to have my Ubuntu home folder contain links to the equivalent Windows folders. Unfortunately U1 will not allow you to sync folders that are not within your home folder, so knowing where the folder is located does not help in this case. It just seems a bit stupid that I am able to sync folders within the linked Pictures folder (which are effectively located, from Ubuntu's point of view, in /media/windows/Users/username/Pictures/foldername) but not sync the Pictures folder itself.